# Hosting restful web service in java on a real web server?

Tags: java, android, rest, web-hosting

I am new to programming.

I have a project where I have a Java web application connected to a MySQL database. We created a RESTFul service to let the resources to be accessed on android application.

To demonstrate i want to host this on a real server.

Where can I host this? Do I need something special for RESTful services? What knid of server do I need?

Comment: How are you running it now?

Comment: on tomcat? with eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you don't need any special server as long as your application can receive http requests and send http response ( I assume you restful service runs on http).

However most of the Java Restful services run on some kind of Java Application Server which support Java Servlet Specifications like Tomcat.

You can host it at home (if you have good internet connection and static ip), AWS or at some hosting company. Some companies provide installations or you can install one yourself on the VM provided

Comment: do you have any specific name? that would be great help thanks

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer: Tomcat, Jetty, Resin

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Java service then you'll need a Java web server.  Look at Jetty, TomCat and Apache.

If you are new, go with Jetty as it's the smallest.